# I'm getting an Expo Devtools Error when I start Metro after updating Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I have just updated Expo to version 5.3.0, and now I am getting this error:

**"Error loading DevTools, No scheme specified for development client"**

The error appears on a black screen in the browser instead of the expected devtools. The same thing happens when I run either "yarn start" or "npm start".

I have tried reinstalling Expo again, and reinitiating my project again.

So what is the scheme? And how do I include it in my project?

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that in the command line I was also getting this error: **"Linking is disabled because the client scheme cannot be resolved"**. I did a search and found a solution on GitHub: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4140.

**Solution:**

```
npx uri-scheme
```

And then

```
npx uri-scheme add project-name
```

Answer (score 4):

`yarn start` or `npm start` maybe running `expo start --dev-client`
change it to `expo start` in

> package.json

[image: package.json]

Comment: Thank you! I had accidentally run `expo prebuild` and this was the last thing I needed to revert to get back to the managed workflow.

Answer (score 3):

Try running "expo start" instead.